# How to get html to render on blog posts

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, blogs

I have a blog that saves input from html input tags, saves them as XML into a sqlite3 database, and then finally renders the content inside of this tag.

```
<p>
  <b>Content:</b>
  <%= @post.content %>
</p>
```

I need this .content to be able to render HTML. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these kind of situations, you have to use either:

- Markup language like [RedCloth](http://redcloth.org/),
- Or an editor like [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/).

Using CKEditor is a breeze with the [CKEditor gem](https://github.com/jeremy6d/rails-ckeditor)

And please note if you are using Rails 3, you need to explicitly say you want raw HTML, like this:

```
<p>
  <b>Content:</b>
  <%= raw @post.content %>
</p>
```

Comment: but of course take into account that `raw` using maybe very dangerous ;)

Comment: Check out the Railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/272-markdown-with-redcarpet